# PHP breadcrumb array, link is not full

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I go the following code for breadcrumb :

```
<?php

class Breadcrumb
{
   private $breadcrumb;
   private $separator = ' / ';
   private $domain = 'example.org';

   public function build($array)
   {
      $breadcrumbs = array_merge(array('Home' => ''), $array);
      $count = 0;
      foreach($breadcrumbs as $title => $link) {
         $this->breadcrumb .= '
         <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
            <a href="'.$this->domain. '/'.$link.'" itemprop="url">
               <span itemprop="title">'.$title.'</span>
            </a>
         </span>';

         $count++;
         if($count !== count($breadcrumbs)) {
            $this->breadcrumb .= $this->separator;
         }
      }
      return $this->breadcrumb;
   }
}

 ?>
```

I call it as follow:

```
<?php
$breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
  echo $breadcrumb->build(array(
  $pageTitle => 'about',
    'More' => 'more.php'
  )); 
?>
```

pageTitle is a var on top of each page.

The output is correct and shows: Home / About / More
but, the link on each one of them is as follow:

```
Home: example.org
About: example.org/about
More: example.org/more.php
```

And I am looking for output like that: example.org/about/more.php

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you just replace more.php with about/more.php?

Comment: Yes, but I am looking to see if there is any solution other then typing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the links as you progress through your loop...

```
$bclink = '';
foreach($breadcrumbs as $title => $link) {
    if ($link != '') {
        $bclink .= '/' . $link;
    }
    $this->breadcrumb .= '
        <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
            <a href="'.$this->domain.$bclink.'" itemprop="url">
                <span itemprop="title">'.$title.'</span>
            </a>
        </span>';

    $count++;
    if($count !== count($breadcrumbs)) {
        $this->breadcrumb .= $this->separator;
    }
}
```